# How to make a laptop the primary display of another laptop

Tags: windows-8, windows-vista, display, vga

I have two laptops, one running Windows 8, and the other one running Windows Vista. The one running vista has a broken LCD, and it is impossible for me to read anything that is on its screen, but I can tell when it's on and logged in. I also have a VGA cable connecting the two, so that I could use the Windows 8 laptop as a display for the broken one. However, I can not get this to work properly. Does anyone know how, maybe through keyboard shortcuts, I could make the vista computer change its primary display to the Windows 8 one?

Comment: Use remote dektop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The VGA port on a laptop is output only, it cannot be used as an input. You'll need to connect a device with VGA input like a monitor or TV if you want to use an external display.